# MySQL where to place stored procedures?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

This may sound extremely dim, but where exactly do I place a stored procedure when working with PHP & MySQL?

I ask only because every single website and page I've seen that describes stored procedures jumps right into what they are, how they work, and a multitude of examples for their viewers - and doesn't cover where they go.

Take this [website](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/introduction-to-sql-stored-procedures.aspx) as an example. Nothing on where they are placed, but everything on what they are and how they work.

Is there a location in the MySQL database (or somewhere in phpMyAdmin in my case) they are placed, and then called via PHP, or are they created and stored in a PHP script on a webpage?

Cheers, Luke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored Procedures are stored in the database - this will help you: [MySQL 5.0 Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: (and are scoped at the database level - just like table names)